# Can I tell TypeScript that my function returns a type that one of its parameters returns?

Tags: typescript

Lets's say that I have a function that accesses the values within an object.

```js
// TypeScript
function access<T, K extends keyof T>(object: T, key: K): T[K] {
    return object[key];
}

const object: Record<string, any> = {
    zero: 0,
    one: 1,
    two: "2",
};
const one = access(object, "one");
const two = access(object, "two");
```

With this, TypeScript can work out that `one` is a number and `two` is a string. So far so good.

But now, let's say that I want to potentially modify the key that I get within my `access` function.

```js
// JavaScript
function identity(x) {
    return x;
}

function access(object, key, modify = identity) {
    return modify(object[key]);
}

const object = {
    zero: 0,
    one: 1,
    two: "2",
};
const zero = access(object, "zero", Boolean);
const one = access(object, "one");
const two = access(object, "two", Number);
```

Is there a way that I can tell TypeScript that `zero` is a boolean, `one` is a number, and `two` is a number as well? As in, **can I tell TypeScript that my `access` function is going to return a type that its `modify` parameter returns?**

I've tried things like this:

```js
function identity(x: any): typeof x {
    return x;
}

function access<T, K extends keyof T, V extends any>(object: T, key: K, modify: (x: V) => typeof x = identity): V {
    return modify(object[key]);
}
```

Although this correctly identifies `zero` and `two`, it leaves `one` as unknown.

I've also tried this:

```js
function access<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>(object: T, key: K, modify: (x: V) => typeof x = identity): V {
    return modify(object[key]);
}
```

But this flags the third parameter up as an error because it's expecting the `modify` function to return the same type that it's given.

Is there a TypeScript way to do this, or am I just over-complicating things?

Comment: TypeScript cannot verify that `identity` will behave correctly for all generics, but you can use a type assertion to work around it.  [This version](https://tsplay.dev/wQq6Zw) is probably how I'd do it.  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I think that's exactly what I'm looking for - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we didn't worry about using `identity` as a [default function argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), then the correct typing would look like:

```
function access<T extends object, K extends keyof T, R>(
  object: T, key: K, modify: (v: T[K]) => R) {
  return modify(object[key]);
}
```

Here we're just adding a new type `R` corresponding to the return type of `modify`, where `modify`'s input type is the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T[K]`.  It behaves as expected:

```
const object = {
  zero: 0,
  one: 1,
  two: "2",
};
function identity<T>(x: T) {
  return x;
}

const zero = access(object, "zero", Boolean); // boolean
const one = access(object, "one", identity); // number
const two = access(object, "two", Number); // number
```

but of course you need to actually pass in `identity` if you want it.

---

It gets more complicated when trying to use `identity` as a default argument.  There's a disconnect in TypeScript that makes it hard to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) with default function arguments.  [Default type arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) don't exactly line up the way most people want.  The problem has to do with the fact that *callers* choose type arguments, but here we want the *implementation* to choose it if someone doesn't pass in a `modify` property.  And it just doesn't work that way.  There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#56315](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56315) for something better.

Until and unless that happens, the easiest way to work around it is to use a default generic type argument (when `modify` is `indentity`, then `R` above should be `T[K]`, so we default `R = T[K]`) and then just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `identity` is of the requisite type `(v: T[K]) => R`:

```
function identity<T>(x: T) {
  return x;
}

function access<T extends object, K extends keyof T, R = T[K]>(
  object: T, key: K, modify = identity as (v: T[K]) => R) {
  return modify(object[key]);
}
```

That still works the way you want:

```
const object = {
  zero: 0,
  one: 1,
  two: "2",
};
const zero = access(object, "zero", Boolean);
const one = access(object, "one");
const two = access(object, "two", Number);
```

(The reason you need a type assertion is because nothing stops a crazy person from explicitly specify type arguments like

const crazy = access<typeof object, "one", string>(object, "one");
// const crazy: string

which would be a bizarre thing to do. But the compiler can't be sure that won't happen.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhEUCW8kG8BQeSSAZgK7DwAuGA9sEhgCYTDWUCeAPACoB8AFAA8AXEm4BKXISJIAThEqlZ9QQG5pAX2lkK1OkgSIoUHkgiDKLRlCQ0ARgCsIVADRIA0mYtWbAawjsNMRibgBKAtJE9k5Uotxu-uyi7m5gNIwYxElI-ABucQDa7gC6kgC8vEihkvgycgpK9GkZWfzRzpQFiaXqRFpE8HRQlLaOHUhlUnUAXhCyNKIADC6RtsAQogCMK3WUAO4LSABEAExHO0gavUiDwMNIs-MTBvBGUG1jrsePNOeoNDQADYQEDAcSqJAAekhSDsAOBoOkt3udGQk0M0He7S+R1RfyYLDY7HBUJhwFIYDscyRQxG+xozwxxg+MUobiO9L+ADkKVTZCToUhyZTqVo8KBILAEMgAOoYSgACwAIhBiCBSICRrUSOQqLR6ATWPKuHwhHEaqt5IplEg1JoCEQdHr9EyTNwvJZgNZRqy3J5zJ7vYkgiEqs9uEVihE6tjKHEEgFkql0pl2M9DUSDDY8oUSuVKtUpjIrY0kM1UyyOl0Aj17QQaXcRrHntqiD8lhcoustp2kPTRKdzpprsiRj9Ga9MZWcT8-ih4SCwSPaWs0S83tO2cc8eCG-d6RON7H2Zy3DyRfz1HuRvBZCBpmn0ZPjJwODAICHj9v1n9hrIMMAADmAhfriP67kQgqjjcd4PqIf4AYBeAaEAA)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in TypeScript, you can define a function's return type using the ReturnType utility type with key of to refer to a property of one of its parameters. For example:

```js
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K] {
    return obj[key];
}

const person = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 30
};

const name: string = getProperty(person, 'name');
const age: number = getProperty(person, 'age');
```

In this example, the `getProperty` function returns a type that matches the type of the specified property of its parameter.